How to make this hook works in TikZ?
Question
What do I need to change to make myhook work?
Objective

create a dia(gram) in TikZ,
where coordinates depend on parameters (options)
and resulting coordinates can be accessed or used (here: (HL), (HR) and (KL) )

Background
I based my code on the solution user194703 proposed and the source code of samcarters wonderful TikZducks package, ... as far as I understand it.
I have little experience using pgfkeys ...
Code in brief

initialization (?)  \tikzset{dia/.search ...
shortcut to retrieve key values \def\pv#1 ...
scoped \newcommand\dia[1]{ ...
some tests in the document


Observations
1st row of drawings:

(1a) shows the result when the initial key values are used.

(1b) changed length parameters, while (1c) also changed orientation parameters. Though I can access the internal coordinates (\draw[dashed] ...) after having called \dia{}, it doesn't seem to be right. In contrast, accessing key values (black, \pv...) seem to give the initial values, not the latest: this seems to be a scoping issue, which I don't understand enough so far.

back to \newcommand\dia[1]{ ... putting Tikz commands, like \node, right after calling \pic seem to work correctly (blue text).


2nd row of drawings:

however, trying to mimick the approach from TikZducks by setting myhook after \pic AND defining \newcommand{\myhook}{ inside a tikzpicture environment doesn't seem to have any noticable effect.

Code
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ initializing (?) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tikzset{
    dia/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
    dia/.cd,
    L hh/.initial=.5, L ll/.initial=1,      % lengths
    O hh/.initial=0 , O ll/.initial=-90,    % orientations
}

% ~~~ shortcut ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\pv#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dia/#1}}%

% ~~~ a dia(gram) object for TIKZ ~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\dia[1]{
 \begin{scope}[
    dia/.pic={
        % ~~~ HH ~~~ (kind of base) ~~~~~
        \draw  (\pv{O hh}:-\pv{L hh}) coordinate (HL) 
            -- (\pv{O hh}: \pv{L hh}) coordinate (HR);  
%
        % ~~~ L ~~~~~ (dependent coordinates)
        \draw (HL) -- +(\pv{O ll}:\pv{L ll}) coordinate (KL);
%
        % ~~~ some visualization ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[red]      (HL) circle[radius=.1];
        \draw[green]    (HR) circle[radius=.1];
        },
    ]
    \tikzset{dia/.cd,#1}    
    \pic {dia};                                           % OK
    \node[anchor=east,blue] at (KL) {\pv{O ll} (inside)}; % OK
    \csname myhook \endcsname   % doesn't seem to hook
 \end{scope}
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}    
 % ~~~ (1) works (let's me access the nodes), but seems to be suspicious ? ~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~ (1a) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \dia{}
 
    % ~~~ (1b) are iternal nodes accessible? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \dia{xshift=4cm,L hh=1, L ll=1.5,}
    \draw[dashed] (HR) -- (KL) node[anchor=north]{\pv{O ll}}; % ok: shows default
 
    % ~~~ (1c) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \dia{xshift=9cm,L hh=1, L ll=1.5,O hh=20, O ll=-110,}
    \draw[dashed](HR) -- (KL) node[anchor=north]{\pv{O ll}};  % NOK: should be -110
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \bigskip
 % ~~~ (2) tried to hook, without success ~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begingroup
      \newcommand{\myhook}{
        \node[anchor=west] at (KL) {hello};       
      }
      \dia{O ll = -140}
    \endgroup
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks @cfr, always something to learn from you :)

It is basically a scoping/grouping issue. All LaTeX environments create groups. pgfkeys always sets values locally. Coordinates are treated specially and smuggled out of scopes within tikzpictures. Key-values are not.
Maybe something like this?
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ initializing (?) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tikzset{
  dia/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  dia/.cd,
  L hh/.initial=.5, L ll/.initial=1,      % lengths
  O hh/.initial=0 , O ll/.initial=-90,    % orientations
}

% ~~~ shortcut ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\pv#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dia/#1}}%
\tikzset{%
  dia/.pic={
    % ~~~ HH ~~~ (kind of base) ~~~~~
    \draw  (\pv{O hh}:-\pv{L hh}) coordinate (HL) 
    -- (\pv{O hh}: \pv{L hh}) coordinate (HR);  
    %
    % ~~~ L ~~~~~ (dependent coordinates)
    \draw (HL) -- +(\pv{O ll}:\pv{L ll}) coordinate (KL);
    %
    % ~~~ some visualization ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[red]      (HL) circle[radius=.1];
    \draw[green]    (HR) circle[radius=.1];
  },
}
% ~~~ a dia(gram) object for TIKZ ~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\dia[1]{
  \tikzset{dia/.cd,#1}    
  \pic {dia};                                           % OK
  \node[anchor=east,blue] at (KL) {\pv{O ll} (inside)}; % OK
  \ifcsname myhook\endcsname\myhook\fi
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}    
% ~~~ (1) works (let's me access the nodes), but seems to be suspicious ? ~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % ~~ (1a) ~~~~~~~~~~~
  \dia{}
  
  % ~~~ (1b) are iternal nodes accessible? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \dia{xshift=4cm,L hh=1, L ll=1.5,}
  \draw[dashed] (HR) -- (KL) node[anchor=north]{\pv{O ll}}; % ok: shows default
  
  % ~~~ (1c) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \dia{xshift=4cm,L hh=1, L ll=1.5,O hh=20, O ll=-110,}
  \draw[dashed](HR) -- (KL) node[anchor=north]{\pv{O ll}};  % NOK: should be -110
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
% ~~~ (2) tried to hook, without success ~~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begingroup
  \newcommand{\myhook}{
    \node[anchor=west] at (KL) {hello};       
  }
  \dia{O ll = -140}
  \endgroup
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Great: simple and effective. Took me a while to understand your modification \ifcsname myhook\endcsname\myhook\fi. If I get it right about this old e-Tex primitive, the first part 'til \endcsname checks, whether or not the token (here: myhook) was defined (anywhere). If true, it executes \myhook, else does nothing. // I checked "anywhere" by moving \newcommand{\myhook}{ ...somewhere else, and it compiles WITH the expected output. // Thanks again.

BTW for readers: best source I found about \ifcsname is "TEX in a Nutshell" by Petr Olšák, which explains it very briefly  https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

@MS-SPO I've been reading 2e source ....

Ok, thank you. I've seen it earlier, and who wants to have a look: https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e

@MS-SPO It was an explanation rather than a recommendation ;).
